# Boundary of $X=\{1/2^n\,:\, n\in\mathbb N\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What is the boundary of the set $X=\left\{\frac1{2^n}\,:\, n\in\mathbb N\right\}\subset \mathbb R$ when $\mathbb R$ is endowed with the standard topology?

I think $\partial X=X\cup\{0\}$. Is that right?

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of boundary? Does your candidate fulfill that definition?

Comment: The closure of $X$ is certainly $X\cup\{0\}$, and $X$ has no interior...

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The boundary is the closure minus the interior. The closure is $X\cup\{0\}$ and the interior is empty. Therefore, the boundary is $X\cup\{0\}$.